# Garbled characters in cookie

Tags: javascript, encoding, cookies

I store Chinese characters in cookie but the cookie value changes to garbled characters. What should I do?

```
function createCookie(name, value, days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
}

createCookie("city", decodeURI('%e6%b8%a9%e5%b7%9e%e5%b8%82'));
alert(decodeURI('%e6%b8%a9%e5%b7%9e%e5%b8%82')); // The Chinese characters are correct
alert(document.cookie); //The Chinese characters are corrupted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, works for me.

```
createCookie("city", '%e6%b8%a9%e5%b7%9e%e5%b8%82'); //do not decode chinese characters
alert(decodeURI('%e6%b8%a9%e5%b7%9e%e5%b8%82')); 
alert(decodeURI(document.cookie));
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll just have to encode the value (and maybe the name if that can contain Chinese characters too) before setting the cookie (I'm not sure what encoding `decodeURI` is using, but presumably, whatever encoding that it, it has an encode verb to match the decode one, y?-)